# Python code cannot identify green color pixels in an image where mac can

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am trying to list down pixels in an image where color is green. With the same code and image I am getting list of green color pixels on my mac. But the code when running on raspberry pi not able to identify green pixels.

```
if pix[num,i]==(0,255,0):
    print(num, i)
```

Comment: Is there an alpha channel? Are the numbers in the range 0-255 or 0-1? More details are needed.

Comment: I have not added alpha channel, even not sure how to do it. number are in the range 0-255 e.g (77, 202, 64), (60, 145, 44)

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve], as it stands your question does not have enough information to answer.